# What is a 'non-nominal type' in Swift?

Tags: swift

I see this error when trying to extend unorthodox 'types' like `(Int, Int)`, or `Any`:

> Non-nominal type 'Any' cannot be extended

So what makes a type non-nominal? What's the difference between a non-nominal type like `Any` or `(Int)` and a regular nominal type like `Int`?

Comment: I was getting this error by using a typealiase between two protocols and trying to extend the combined protocol...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat of a guess (edit: it's wrong, look at [Brent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396546/2177402)), but here goes:

`Any` is a protocol, not an actual type. The word "Nominal" implies naming (based on the root of the word).

So you can't extend `Any` because it's a protocol, not an actual type, and you can't extend `(Int, Int)` because that's just a tuple literal, again not an actual type that you could specify by name.

---

#### Update:

You can, of course, extend protocols. `Any` is not a protocol, it's (shocker) a non-nominal type which is something else. Read [Brent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396546/2177402); he did a good job.

Comment: It's different to a protocol though. `AnyObject` is a protocol and extending that gives the error: `Protocol AnyObject cannot be extended`. So `Any` is something different

Comment: `Any` is a `typealias` of an empty protocol it's full definition is `typealias Any = protocol<>`. You can combine protocols that way: `typealias MyPrintableSequance = protocol<Printable, Sequence>` and use it as if it was a protocol

Comment: I didn't know that protocols could be combined, that's good to know. how did you get the full definition of Any?

Comment: @sjeohp I typed `var x: Any` in the playground, then `<cmd> - clicked` on "Any" - that file is just headers, but in the case of a typealias, the header is the whole thing

Comment: but doesn't Swift have protocol extensions as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521)? I'm in Swift 3 and still get the same error when attempting to extend `Any`. I know it's a terrible idea to extend `Any` but out of curiosity I'm trying to do it

Comment: You absolutely can extend functionality of protocols.

Answer (score 127):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131511/41222) is incorrect; the actual answer comes from a deep and esoteric part of Swift's type system.

Most types in Swift are *nominal types*—they're "named" types declared in a particular module as part of user code. Seemingly primitive types like `Int` and `Array` are actually structs defined in the `Swift` module, which is automatically imported into every Swift source file. Even `Optional` itself is an enum in the `Swift` module, although the compiler adds a little bit of magic like optional chaining and force-unwrapping.

The few exceptions are called "non-nominal types". There may be others, but the main ones are:

- Function types, like `(Int) -> String`
- Tuple types, like `(Int, String)`
- Metatypes, like `String.Type` (the type of the expression `String.self`)
- Existentials, like `CustomStringConvertible & Error`

Existentials deserve a little more explanation. An existential contains a value whose exact type has been abstracted away, but which is known to conform to a certain set of protocols. For example:

```
// You can put anything that conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` in `x`
let x: CustomStringConvertible

// You can put anything that conforms to both `CustomStringConvertible` 
// and `Error` in `y`
let y: CustomStringConvertible & Error

// You can put anything in `z`; `Any` is an existential that doesn't
// require you to conform to any particular protocols
let z: Any
```

Non-nominal types all simply combine other types together in some ad-hoc way. (They're sometimes called "structural types" because they define some kind of general structure for other types to slot into.) They don't need to be explicitly defined, and they don't belong to any particular module—FooKit's `(Int, String)` is the same as BarKit's `(Int, String)`. But all of their behavior is defined by the language—a non-nominal type can't have methods or properties of its own, can't conform to protocols, and therefore can't be extended.

So you can't extend `Any` because `Any` is a special thing that's built into the language, just like a function type or a tuple type. It just happens to have a name written in letters, not in punctuation.

(So why can you extend `CustomStringConvertible`? Because, depending on context, `CustomStringConvertible` might mean *the protocol* or it might mean an *existential containing a value conforming to the protocol*. When you write `extension CustomStringConvertible`, you're extending the protocol, but when you write `let x: CustomStringConvertible`, you're declaring a variable whose type is "existential containing a value conforming to the protocol". This is kind of confusing, and some of Swift's maintainers would actually like to require that the existential be written as `Any<CustomStringConvertible>` to make it more clear. Not terribly likely to happen now that they're trying to preserve source stability, though.)

Comment: `Void` is another non-nominal type

Comment: @IslamQ.: To be more precise, Void is a [`typealias`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift#L53) for an empty tuple.

Comment: Why are types like `CustomStringConvertible & Error` not called Determinatives? Existential should indicate a kind of feature required to exist. In terms of programming code execution, it is invalid.

Comment: Some of the compiler's terminology for protocols, like "existential" and "witness", comes from analogies with mathematical predicate logic. The compiler developers understand that these terms are not very user-friendly and try to keep them out of diagnostics and documentation, but unfortunately nobody has settled on a better user-facing term for "existential", so that one has leaked out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

[[Swift types]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219141/4770877)

```
Non-nominal type 'Pair' (aka '(key: String, value: String)') cannot be extended
```

Swift operates by two types:

1. `named type` or `nominal type` or `type with name` like:

   - `class`
   - `structure`
   - `enumeration`
   - `protocol`
2. `compound type` or `non-nominal type` or `type without name` like:

   - `function`
   - `tuple`

This error you get when `extends` compound type. For example

```
public typealias Pair = (key: String, value: String)

public extension Pair { //compile time error

}
```

As a variant to use `extends` functionality you can use `named type` instead