# Trying to implement ?.let pattern in Swift, is it even possible?

Tags: swift, kotlin

I've been porting code back and forth between Swift and Kotlin. Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723729/swift-if-let-and-else-in-kotlin), I've been using `?.let { } ?: run {}` as replacements for the many places I use `if let ... { } else {}` in Swift.

I've really come to like the Kotlin expression though. In my opinion it's more general than the keyword specific `if let` concoction. So for parity's sake--or at least for the sake of learning by trying silly experiments--I thought I'd try to implement the `let` construct in Swift.

Because `let` is a keyword in Swift, I discovered right away that I'd need to put backticks, or use a different name, like `cull`. That led to this uncompilable code:

```
extension Any {
    func cull<R>(block:(Self) -> R) -> R {
        return block(self)
    }
}
```

which given my apprentice level skills, probably has numerous problems. But most importantly, I'm informed that I can't extend Any (which is [explained in better detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131466/what-is-a-non-nominal-type-in-swift/44396546#44396546)).

So Any can't be extended. Is there any other language construct I *can* use to make it so that I can implement something like Kotlin's `let`? Basically:

```
<expression>.foo { <expressionResult> in ... }
```

As a bonus/aside question, I think even if there is a way (I do hope there is just so I can learn), it won't be the same, because the Kotlin one can be used for control flow because I can do a non local return from the Kotlin one, but not from a Swift closure. Is that also correct?

CLARIFICATION

Basically, I can implement the Kotlin `let` pattern for designated types:

```
protocol Cullable {}

extension Cullable {
    func cull<R>(_ block:(Self) -> R) -> R {
        return block(self)
    }
}

extension Int:Cullable { }

42.cull { thing in print(thing) } // this will print 42
```

This works as I want. But I don't want to have to extend every single non-nominal type in the system to make it work. I just want to define it globally some how. If it was possible.

Comment: It's not possible, because there is no way to have the "foo" part captured and passed into whatever function you concoct. `if let` is a language-feature, not a library feature

Comment: See `CLARIFICATION` @Alexander.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just write an extension on `Optional`, it's not much different.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are actually trying to accomplish? Like give the Kotlin code you are trying to replicate in Swift? I'm a little confused because the ?.let in Kotlin is actually, in my opinion, a much worse option than what Swift has. In most cases, I'd much rather have a Swifty guard let or if let than a Kotlin ?.let.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I think such a method already exists in `Optional`. Although this is only for optionals, at least it solves your problem of the lack of `?.let`. The method is called [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map).

```
let optional: String? = "hello"
optional.map { print($0) } // prints hello
// note how I did not unwrap the optional. I called "map" directly on the optional, not the wrapped "String".
```

You can `map` the value to into another value, or `Void`, like I did above.

I don't think you can have a `let` method on everything.

[`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) is also available if you want to return an optional inside the closure.

And yes, after looking at what "non-local return" means in Kotlin, I don't think you can do the same in Swift. Those curly brace thingys are "closures". They are "closed", so you can't `return` the surrounding closure in an inner closure.