# How can I return a Swift generic from a general extension?

Tags: swift, generics, types, self, any

If I had a generic class like this:

```swift
class Generic<T: Any> {
    var object: T
    init(object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }
}
```

I could access the object from the initializer like this:

```swift
Generic(object: "Hello World").object.count // 11
```

As this generic class works for `Any` type, how would I extend all types to return a object of that generic class?

I mean something like this:

```swift
extension Any {
    var generic: Generic<Self> {
        Generic(object: self)
    }
}
```

So I can call:

```swift
"Hello World".generic.object.count // 11
```

I am confused with all the `Any`, `AnyObject`, `Self`, `self`, `Type` and so on.

UPDATE:

For example, how would I extend all `Comparable` with the computed properties `array: Array<Comparable>`? I am thinking of something like:

```swift
extension Comparable {
    var array: Array<Comparable> {
        Array(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to find out how I would extend all kinds of classes that a generic class could be constrained to by returning an object of that class using an object of the extended class.

Comment: For example writing an extension on `Any` so it is capable to return an array consisting of the object. Like `5.array` returns `[5]`.

Comment: I don't get it. `Generic` is actually an object wrapper. You create an instance with the string and then you get the string back with the `object` property. What is the benefit?

Comment: There is no benefit. It honestly doesn’t make sense. I still would like to know how this could be done.

Comment: You should extend actual types then and not the Any

Comment: Thanks! How would I do that? For example, how would I constrain my `array`-extension to `Comparable`? Something like `extension Any { var array: Array<Self> { Array(self) } }`

Comment: I updated my question with another example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't extend Any, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396546/12846974

Example for Comparable extension:

```
extension Comparable {
    var array: Array<Self> {
        [self]
    }
}
```