# Difference between protocol combining typealias and empty conforming protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Is there a difference between these two in Swift?

- `protocol ABProtocol: AProtocol, BProtocol {}`
- `typealias ABProtocol = AProtocol&BProtocol`

Answer (score 5):

To make things clearer, I will rename the second one to:

```
typealias ABProtocolIntersection = AProtocol & BProtocol
```

I can think of two differences off the top of my head.

If your type conform to `AProtocol` and `BProtocol`, the type is automatically a subtype of `ABProtocolIntersection`, but it *does **not*** automatically conform to `ABProtocol`. After all, `ABProtocol` is a totally different protocol.

Example:

```
class Foo: AProtocol, BProtocol { ... }

func foo<T: ABProtocolIntersection>(type: T.Type) {  }
func bar<T: ABProtocol>(type: T.Type) { }

foo(type: Foo.self) // works
bar(type: Foo.self) // error
```

Another difference is that you can put extensions on `ABProtocol`, but not `ABProtocolIntersection`:

```
extension ABProtocol { } // OK

extension ABProtocolExtension { } // error
```

This is because `ABProtocolIntersection` is a non-nominal type, similar to types like `(Int, Int)` or `(Int) -> String`. See also: [What is a 'non-nominal type' in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24131466/5133585)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a difference. The former defines a new protocol to which types must conform when it is used. The latter only defines a "placeholder" for `AProtocol&BProtocol`

Consider the following code:

```
protocol AProtocol{}
protocol BProtocol{}

protocol ABProtocol1: AProtocol, BProtocol {}
typealias ABProtocol2 = AProtocol & BProtocol

func f1(value: ABProtocol1) {}
func f2(value: ABProtocol2) {}
```

Arguments to `f1` must conform to `ABProtocol1` but arguments to `f2` can conform to `AProtocol` and `BProtocol`. You do not need to explicitly conform types to `ABProtocol2`. For example:

```
struct A: AProtocol, BProtocol
{
}

f1(value: A()) // Error!
f2(value: A()) // OK
```