# Why this swift code cause type-checking error? I'm in Swift 5

Tags: swift

Here's a snippet of swift test code, why this does not working? How to make it working?

```
import UIKit

class SwiftTestController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        test()
    }
    
    func test() {
        let resourceViews: Array<any ResourceView> = []
       // type-checking error in this line.
        let resources = resourceViews.map { $0.resource }
    }
}


protocol ResourceComponent {
    
}

// fine
protocol ResourceView: ResourceComponent {
    associatedtype R: Resource
    var resource: R { get set }
}

// does not working
//protocol ResourceView: UIView, ResourceComponent {
//    associatedtype R: Resource
//    var resource: R { get set }
//}

// does not working
//protocol ResourceView: UIView {
//    associatedtype R: Resource
//    var resource: R { get set }
//}

protocol Resource {}
```

Below is a image for detail error message!
[image]

let `ResourceView` does not inherit(constraint to) `UIView` works fine.

I've submitted a [issue](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/63933).

Comment: in your func test() you declared let resourceViews as an Array of "any ResourceView". Have you tried to use an array of ResourceView? Would be my first idea to declare a correct type for your array.
Change let resourceViews : Array<any ResourceView> = [] 
to
let resourceViews: Array<ResourceView> = []

Comment: It looks like the Swift compiler crashed instead of giving you a proper, readable error message.

Comment: @Iskandir No, not working.
 
Use of protocol `ResourceView` as a type must be written `any ResourceView`.

Comment: @Sweeper It crashed because it cannot type-checking.

Comment: Well, crashing is not the expected behaviour for "cannot type check", is it? It should at least output a diagnostic. In any case, this is definitely a compiler bug.

Comment: `Why is it crashing?` - because it's a compiler bug. Report it at https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/ or via Feedback Assistant

Comment: @Gereon Have you run this code ever? And does it work fine for you or not?

Comment: No, it doesn't compile in Xcode 14.2

Comment: @K.F Stop saying "work" and "doesn't work". It's meaningless.  The issue here is whether the code compiles or fails to compile and, if the latter, whether the compiler  emits a coherent error message or crashes.

Comment: @matt I say working for the compiler side, just as you mean, compiles or fails to compile.

Comment: So say that, because "work" doesn't mean that.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently issue [#63751](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/63751)

According to the bug report, this is an unimplemented part of [SE-309 Unlock existentials for all protocols](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md), and happens whenever you open an existential that is also an l-value, like a class-bound protocol type.

Anyway, I've found that declaring `resourceViews` to be an intersection type between `ResourceView` and `UIView` to work:

```
protocol ResourceView:  ResourceComponent { // remove the class bound
    ...
}

let resourceViews: Array<any ResourceView & UIView> = []
```

The type constraints on the `map` line are practically the same here (I think), but somehow Swift is happy with this.

The difference here is of course that non-`UIView`s can now conform to `ResourceView`, but at the end of the day they can't go in the `resourceViews` array, so I think this could be a viable solution for now. There are a few more minor differences that I don't think matters too much in your case, which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74232417/5133585).

Maybe a bit of renaming would also help :)

```
protocol ResourceComponent {
    
}

protocol ResourceBox:  ResourceComponent {
    associatedtype R: Resource
    var resource: R { get set }
}

protocol Resource {
    
}

typealias ResourceView = any ResourceBox & UIView

let resourceViews: Array<ResourceView> = []
```

Comment: Thx! But this code does not compile:

```func foo(_ resourceView: ResourceView) {
    resourceView.resource = nil
}```

Cannot assign to property: `resourceView` is a `let` constant

Comment: Yes, in my case.

Comment: No! Constrained the `ResourceBox` to `class` or `NSObject` will cause that `type checking` issue.

Comment: Yah, that works! And the `foo` not need to be generic.

Comment: I didn't know about implicitly opening existentials so I'm still benefitting from your answer in a different way.