# iOS App Crashes when splitting out protocol into multiple protocols and combining them using typealias

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, type-alias

I have the following protocol

```
protocol Three {
    var a1: Bool { get }
    var a2: Bool { get }
    var c1: Int { get }
    func test()
}
```

I then have a struct conforming to this protocol

```
struct ThreeTest: Three {
    var text: String
    
    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

// A
extension ThreeTest {
    var a1: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    var a2: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

// B
extension ThreeTest {
    func test() {
        print("test")
    }
}

// C
extension ThreeTest {
    var c1: Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
struct ViewModel {
    var three: Three
    
    init() {
        three = ThreeTest("hello")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vm = ViewModel()
        print("all good")
    }
}
```

This works fine and prints `all good` to the console.

What I do next is to split the protocol into multiple protocols and combine them using a `typealias`

```
protocol A {
    var a1: Bool { get }
    var a2: Bool { get }
}

protocol B {
    func test()
}

protocol C {
    var c1: Int { get }
}

typealias Three = A & B & C
```

If you run this in a test app, you will see this compiles and works fine as well with no issues, however, this exact same thing crashes my app with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x102b7ff38)`

**While I am aware that you will not be able to give me a fix for my situation as you do not have enough info and cannot reproduce do**

**My question is, What happens differently behind the scenes at run time when you have one protocol vs splitting the same requirements into multiple protocols and combining multiple protocols using typealias ?**

Comment: @Sweeper - this is what I mentioned, this code runs fine on its own so you won't be able to reproduce. My question was - what is different that happens during run time when using one protocol vs. combining multiple protocols using typealis.

Comment: From looking at the assembly output difference using godbolt.org ([without -O](https://www.diffchecker.com/MZR8BsHL/) and [with -O](https://www.diffchecker.com/6k9SNSYV/)), it appears that using a typealias of the intersection type takes up more memory generally.

Comment: Have you also tried `protocol Three: A, B, C {}`? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74232417/5133585) could be related.